# Is it possible to read images without ImageIO?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to read an image and deliver it through a Java socket. But there are some bits that does not fit. When viewing in a diff tool I realized that all numbers bigger than 127 were truncated.

So I wanted to just convert it to a char[] array and return it instead. Now I'm getting a complette different image, perhaps due to char's size.

```
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename), BUFSIZ)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFSIZ];
            while (in.read(buffer) != -1) {
                response.append(new String(buffer));
                out.print(response.toString());
                response.setLength(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

This is my reading and delivering code.

I've read many times to use ImageIO but I want to do it without, since I don't know whether it's an image or not. (And what about other file types like executables?)

So, is there any way to convert it to something like an unsigned byte that'll be delivered correctly on the client? Do I have to use something different than read() to achieve that?

Comment: Binary data isn't a `String`.

Comment: Bytes are fine so long as they stay bytes. As soon as you convert them to characters (as you have to when you create a `String`), you have to face the problem of bytes being signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Writers` are for character data. Use the `OutputStream.` And you're making the usual mistake of assuming that `read()` filled the buffer.

The following loop will copy anything correctly. Memorize it.

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appended it to respone since it stores the http header on The First iteration. It should be ok to send it before I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Repeat after me: a `char` is not a `byte` and it's not a code point.

Repeat after me: a `Writer` is not an `OutputStream`.

```
    try (OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream();
         BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename), BUFSIZ)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFSIZ];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer))) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

(this is from memory, check the args for write()).

Comment: a char is not a byte and it's not a code point. Thanks for pointing out!